# Why will my UIScrollView not zoom the UIImageView within it?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a very simple project where in `viewDidLoad` I simply have:

```
    sv = UIScrollView(frame: view.frame)
    sv.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(sv)

    let iv = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "earth-small.jpg"))
    sv.addSubview(iv)

    sv.contentSize = iv.image!.size
    print(iv.image!.size)
    sv.minimumZoomScale = 0.1
    sv.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
    sv.zoomScale = 1.0

    centerMedia()
```

And in addition to that:

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return iv
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    centerMedia()
}

func centerMedia() {
    var left = CGFloat(0.0)
    var top = CGFloat(0.0)

    if sv.contentSize.width < sv.bounds.size.width {
        left = (sv.bounds.size.width - sv.contentSize.width) / 2.0
    }

    if sv.contentSize.height < sv.bounds.size.height {
        top = (sv.bounds.size.height - sv.contentSize.height) / 2.0
    }

    sv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: left, bottom: top, right: left)
}
```

Which seems to me like everything I should need to have in order to zoom. But the image view (which has a 500pt x 300pt image) never grows or shrinks if I zoom in or out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: let iv = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "earth-small.jpg")) -> Are you sure that you are not saving the image view only method-wide?

Comment: @JonasFranz I owe you one. AHHHH. So simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let iv = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "earth-small.jpg"))
```

You have to declare iv class-wide. (see comments)